# errors in simple for loops

Tags: matrix, programming, infinite-loop

Im trying to run the following code, which I have translated from Matlab. I created a for loop nested inside another for loop. `mW` is a matrix, and `vMuTilde` is a vector. 
i.e.

```
dw1 = 3; mW = {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}; vMuTilde = {1, 2, 1};
```

I got

> set:write Tag Times is protected

so I tried adding `Clear[v]` and `Clear[p]` thinking it might be related to the fact that I use this variables again and again.

Now I still get this error, and in addition I also get

> "$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of ...".

Now it looks like I'm in an infinite loop, since I don't get to the `"0"` printed at the end.

Thanks a lot
T

```
For[r=1, r<=dw1,r++,
    Clear[v]
    v = mW[[r]];
    mu = vMuTilde[[r]];
    Print[mu];
    For[rr=1, rr<=r-1,rr++,
        Clear[p]
        p = v*mW[[rr]];
        v = v - p*mW[[rr]];
        mu = mu - p*vMuTilde[[rr]];
    ]
    norm = Norma[v];
    Print["dd"];
    mW[[r]] = v / norm;
    vMuTilde[[r]] = mu / norm;
]
Print[0]
```

Comment: Kuba many thanks for the editing.

Comment: Are you sure that `dw1` is less than `Min[Length[mW], Length[vMuTilde]]`?

Comment: Yes, I wrote `dw1 = Dimensions[mW][[1]];` in the line before the loop

Answer (score 2):

Putting the semicolons in the right places removed the error. Also, I replaced `Norma` with `Norm`. I hope `Norma` was not a user defined function.

```
For[r = 1, r <= dw1, r++, Clear[v]; v = mW[[r]];
  mu = vMuTilde[[r]];
  Print[mu];
   For[rr = 1, rr <= r - 1, rr++,
   Clear[p];
    p = v*mW[[rr]];
   v = v - p*mW[[rr]];
   mu = mu - p*vMuTilde[[rr]];];
   norm = Norm[v];
  Print["dd"];
   mW[[r]] = v/norm;
  vMuTilde[[r]] = mu/norm;];
Print[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm running it right now.

Comment: Thanks is not required! You can upvote/accept answers if they have solved your problem.